# How to trigger a function upon 'auto complete' done using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've populated a text box with list of values using autocomplete option available in jquery. I don't know how to trigger a function after user selected a value from auto complete. Please help me out. Here is my code.

```
$(function() {
                 var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                 source: availableProducts,
                 change: function(){alert();}
                                                       });
                 Product.autocomplete('option','change').call(Product);
                      });
```

It's not calling the alert().

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the comma , Check your console for errors

```
         var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
         source: availableProducts , <---
         change: function(){alert();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(function() {
      $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: availableProducts,
                    select: function(event, ui) {      
                               event.preventDefault();
                               alert(1);   
                            }
                 });
```